# Ruby on Rails app transfer to webserver fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have made the GoRails [https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04 tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04%20tutorial). Everything installed. But now I can not transfer my app from the Mac to the Linux web server. The following error with probably git appears. What can I do?

```
cap production deploy    
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.056s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-f9a2d67df5286b2a1eed.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-f9a2d67df5286b2a1eed.sh
    ✔ 02 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.013s
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:mgasche/planer.git HEAD
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 1.065s
00:01 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/planer/shared /home/deploy/planer/releases
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.013s
00:01 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/planer/shared/log /home/deploy/planer/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/planer/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/planer/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/plan…
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.052s
00:01 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/deploy/planer/repo
00:01 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:mgasche/planer.git
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.058s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
    ✔ 02 deploy@192.168.1.140 1.190s
00:02 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/planer/releases/20220501182040
    ✔ 01 deploy@192.168.1.140 0.058s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /home/deploy/planer/releases/20220501182040
      02 fatal: not a valid object name: master
      02 tar: This does not look like a tar archive
      02 tar:
      02 Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Visiting https://github.com/mgasche/planer shows me "this repository is empty". There are no commits and no branches. Which of the zero commits in the zero branches did you plan to deploy? :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the content (commits or empty repository), don't forget that a repository now (since Oct. 2020) has by [default a `main` branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-26-set-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories/), not a `master` branch.

Make sure your `git archive` command takes into account the branch you need.